# Create new Subfolder for given Datestamp and copy files in python

Tags: python

I have a problem and hope someone can help me. I would like to read out a folder and subfolder with python, this is what I do with os.walk. From this list I would like to use the given datestamp to take the files and save them into another folder and create a new subfolder for each existing day. How do you do that kind of thing, I can not handle it. Look forward to answers.

Comment: What do you mean with "given datestamp"? The file's creation/modification date? Look at `os.stat()` and `time.strftime()` in that case.

Comment: Yes exactly, creation date.

Comment: Sorry, okay give you more information. I have 300 gigabytes of data in a directory. I would like to copy the files into a new disk and change the folder structure there. Only there should it be changed. I want to build my folder so, by year, then subfolder month and then after again a subfolder day. Each file should be copied by creation day.

Comment: Right. Use `os.walk()`, as you have, `os.stat()` and `time.strftime()` to get and format the dates, `os.makedirs()` to create the directory structure and `shutil.copy*` to copy the files.

Comment: At a hunch, juuuust in case this is about copying photos, you may want to look into software that can look at the EXIF data instead, such as http://www.amok.am/en/freeware/amok_exif_sorter/ .